# Array with JButtons visible

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have created an array of `JButtons` to appear on a `JFrame`.
What i want is that when I press a button at the screen this will disappear.
The problem is at the `actionListener`, because I have an array so the button with the
event must be something like `buttons[i]`... But I don't know how to turn its visibility off at the action performed so that only the specific one will get visible off.

```
for(int i=0; i<52;i++){
    buttons[i]= new JButton(image);
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new Disappear( ));
    p.add(buttons[i]);
}

private class Disappear implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       // i want the specific button to get visible  
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `((JButton)e.getSource()).setVisible(false);`.

Comment: Thats exactly what i need!!!!!...love u mate :))))

Comment: @LuxxMiner Would you mind posting an answer so that it could be accepted for future viewers :)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved after the following comment:

> Try `((JButton)e.getSource()).setVisible(false);`